# AutoHotkey how to get the thumbnail/icon for a file path

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I have a file path and want to get its thumbnail icon in any image format ex .png

These icons:

[image]

How do I get these?

Comment: Yep, https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/33359-get-icon-for-file/

Comment: @wOxxOm I saw that, but I have no idea how to get an image file from that (I'm trying to render these in HTML)

Comment: Try adapting https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/49658-gdi-save-icon-to-png-trouble/ or find a better example by googling 'ExtractAssociatedIcon save png' or find a command line utility that extracts icons.

Comment: @wOxxOm the google search for `command line utility that extracts icons` looks promising, ty! I tried searching stuff like `cli get iconfrom file path` with no luck